# Unable to use Rapns in staging env (ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with Array failed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm having issues with getting Rapns working in a staging environment. 
Everything works well when running in development on my localhost, but when in Staging (using AWS) I am unable to start the Daemon or call `Rapns.push`

When calling `bundle exec rapns staging` I get no error, but the notifications are not delivered.

When using  `bundle exec rapns staging -f` or when trying to call `Rapns.push` from the rails console, I get:

```
[2013-05-29 06:54:20] [ios] Started, 1 handler.
[2013-05-29 06:54:20] [ERROR] [ios] Exception raised during startup. Notifications will     not be delivered for this app.
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:365:in `<': comparison of     Fixnum with Array failed (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:365:in `add'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/buffered_logger.rb:80:in `add'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/buffered_logger.rb:90:in `error'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.3.0/lib/rapns/logger.rb:53:in `log'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.3.0/lib/rapns/logger.rb:28:in `error'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.3.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:34:in `rescue in sync_app'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.3.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:30:in `sync_app'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.3.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:20:in `block in sync'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.3.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:20:in `each'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.3.0/lib/rapns/daemon/app_runner.rb:20:in `sync'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.3.0/lib/rapns/daemon.rb:47:in `start'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rapns-3.3.0/bin/rapns:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rapns:23:in `load'
    from .../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rapns:23:in `<main>'
```

Again, everything works well on my local machine. Any ideas? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is probably because you are using rubber to deploy to AWS, and it's configuring a different logger (graylog) by default.

To fix this problem, edit the rapns initializer file (config/initializers/rapns.rb) and set the logger to the default rails logger (or your own):

config.logger = Rails.logger # this is the logger set by graylog

hope this helps!